# Convert Array of Arrays into Combination of Arrays and Hashes

Tags: ruby, tree

I have been trying to convert an array of arrays into a combination of arrays and hashes. Let me explain what I am trying to achieve:

***Input:***

```
[['a'], ['b'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'd']]
```

***Expected Output:***

```
[:a => [{:b => [:c, :d]}], :b]
```

What I have come up with so far is:

```
def converter(array)
  tree_hash = {}

  array.each do |path|
    path.each_with_index.inject(tree_hash) do |node, (step, index)|
      step = step.to_sym

      if index < path.size - 1
        node[step] ||= {}
      else
        node[step] = nil
      end
    end
  end

  tree_hash
end
```

and it gives me the following result:

```
converter([['a'], ['b'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'd']])
=> {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>nil, :d=>nil}}, :b=>nil}
```

Can anyone throw some light so that I can solve this problem. Is there any name to this problem, direct graph / indirect graph / graph theory? I am willing to study and improve my knowledge on graphs and trees.

I would appreciate it if you help me on solving this or give me some instructions on how to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you always have two keys. Do the follow up arrays always start with those keys?

Comment: Another example input could be: `[['foo'], ['bar', 'car']]` and the output will be: `[:foo, {:bar => [:car]}]` Does it make sense @ndn? :)

Comment: It actually makes it a bit more complex. What real world use case did this problem originate from?

Comment: @ndn This output will be the input of rails #includes method where you have to follow the structure to represent associations amongst models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def group_by_prefix(elements)
  elements.group_by(&:first).map do |prefix, elements|
    remainders = elements.map { |element| element.drop(1) }.reject(&:empty?)

    if remainders.empty?
      prefix.to_sym
    else
      {prefix.to_sym => group_by_prefix(remainders)}
    end
  end
end

foo = [['a'], ['b'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'd']]
group_by_prefix(foo) # => [{:a=>[{:b=>[:c, :d]}]}, :b]
```

Comment: ndn this also works for me. It's amazing how you guys know so much! Keep doing the good work. Brilliant!

Comment: @SharvyAhmed, this answer doesn't have that much to do with knowledge as with recursion being a sexy beast when it comes to traversing trees. 

Answer (score 1):

It looks very similar to a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

This structure is usually used with Strings (`'apple'`, seen as an Array of chars : `%w(a p p l e)` ), but it can be easily modified to accept an Array of Strings (`%w(bar car)`) :

```
class Node
  attr_reader :key, :children
  def initialize(key, children = [])
    @key = key
    @children = children
  end

  def to_s
    key.to_s
  end

  def to_sym
    key.to_sym
  end
end

class Trie
  attr_reader :root
  def initialize
    @root = Node.new('')
  end

  def self.from_array(array)
    array.each_with_object(Trie.new) { |letters, trie| trie.add(letters) }
  end

  def add(letters)
    node = root
    letters.each do |c|
      next_node = node.children.find { |child| child.key == c }
      if next_node
        node = next_node
      else
        next_node = Node.new(c)
        node.children.push(next_node)
        node = next_node
      end
    end
  end

  def show(node = root, indent = 0)
    puts '  ' * indent + node.to_s
    node.children.each do |child|
      show(child, indent + 1)
    end
  end

  def to_arrays_and_hashes
    recursive_to_arrays_and_hashes(root)[root.to_sym]
  end

  private

  def recursive_to_arrays_and_hashes(node)
    if node.children.empty?
      node.to_sym
    else
      {node.to_sym => node.children.map{|c| recursive_to_arrays_and_hashes(c)}}
    end
  end
end

array1 = [['a'], ['b'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'd']]
array2 = [['foo'], ['bar', 'car']]

[array1, array2].each do |array|
  trie = Trie.from_array(array)
  trie.show
  p trie.to_arrays_and_hashes
end
```

It returns :

```
  a
    b
      c
      d
  b
[{:a=>[{:b=>[:c, :d]}]}, :b]

  foo
  bar
    car
[:foo, {:bar=>[:car]}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I know we are almost there. It's throwing a small error: `NoMethodError: undefined method to_sym for #<Node:0x007fc4e086d240>` Can you take a look?

Comment: Updated, sorry about that.